# MySQL 3 table join on user_id, not getting NULL values, instead duplicate entries

Tags: php, mysql, join

I have 3 tables users, breaks, clock_in_out shown below:

Users:

[image: Users table]

Breaks:

[image: Breaks table]

Clock_in_out table:

[image]

The query I need is something like what I have below:

```
SELECT `clock_in_out`.`created`, `breaks`.`in`, `breaks`.`out`, `clock_in_out`.`user_id`, `users`.`id`,
`clock_in_out`.`loggedin`, `clock_in_out`.`loggedout`, `users`.`firstname`, `users`.`lastname`
FROM (`clock_in_out`)
JOIN `users` ON `users`.`id` = `clock_in_out`.`user_id`
JOIN `breaks` ON `users`.`id` = `breaks`.`user_id`
WHERE `loggedin` LIKE "%2015-03-18%"
AND `clock_in_out`.`user_id` = '88'
ORDER BY `created` ASC
```

This returns:

[image: Returns from query]

The above result is exactly what I need except where there is 1 row in clock_in_out and 2 rows in breaks it adds duplicate values in to clock_in_out's loggedin and loggedout fields (I want these to be NULL)

Answer (score 0):

[LEFT JOIN](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join_left.asp) should work

```
SELECT `clock_in_out`.`created`, `breaks`.`in`, `breaks`.`out`,`clock_in_out`.`user_id`, `users`.`id`,
`clock_in_out`.`loggedin`, `clock_in_out`.`loggedout`, `users`.`firstname`, `users`.`lastname`
FROM (`clock_in_out`)
LEFT JOIN `users` ON `users`.`id` = `clock_in_out`.`user_id`
LEFT JOIN `breaks` ON `users`.`id` = `breaks`.`user_id`
WHERE `loggedin` LIKE "%2015-03-18%"
AND `clock_in_out`.`user_id` = '88'
ORDER BY `created` ASC
```

If not try RIGHT JOIN

Comment: Tried left join and righty join before posting neither work, both get the sam,e result as pictured above.

Comment: LEFT or RIGHTJOIN doesn't modify this comportement.
It only put NULL if the join with the second table doesn't return results on each fields of the second table.

Answer (score 0):

Your query return 2 results because your break table contains 2 lines for the user 88.

Sql return 1 row from your clock_in_out
with the join on users, it completes this row with user information
but with the join on break, it retrieve 2 lines for user 88.

Beacause of that you have 2 results

Comment: So is there no way to get what I want? I need 2 results just not duplicated fields where there should be NULL

Comment: why you need to join to break?

Comment: Because I have coded all my loops that are working out time differences on this result set, I understand I could do two queries but I would have to rewrite quite a lot of code in 4 different views

Comment: Correct, JOIN results inherently create duplicate entries in some columns of the output result set in a one-to-many situation. That's how RDMSs work. Many people write a loop in application code to detect changes between the previous and current row.

Comment: Do you need the first, last or (first in last out) break of a user?

Comment: Would doing a select DISTINCT on the first select statement be a solution..? Think I will try this..

Comment: I need all of them, its a reporting tool